# Github Action Run - Security import is showing "One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid"error

Tags: github-actions

I built the input file (decoded base64 file into p12 file) as CERTIFICATE_PATH, P12_PASSWORD is password in secret, KEYCHAIN_PATH is defined. when I run the command on CLI, I get "1 item imported" success message. but when I run from *.yml file on GitHub action, I get "security: SecKeychainItemImport: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid." error. any suggestions?

security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P $P12_PASSWORD -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH

CERTIFICATE_PATH - file that contains cert.p12 data,
KEYCHAIN_PATH is TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

Comment: Add your yaml workflow definition to your question, otherwise it's difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason in Github actions could be that you are using the wrong environment.
Take a look at this ---> [Difference between Github's "Environment" and "Repository" secrets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957197/difference-between-githubs-environment-and-repository-secrets).

Set the right environment:
`environment: production`

Answer (score 0):

found the issue.. was passing wrong cert file.. once added correct file in the security build , was able to get it working